# Windows 10 21296 AMD - Android emulator WHPX error

Tags: android-emulator, window, amd-processor

I wanted to spin up an Android emulator, and always got the message `The emulator process for AVD was killed`

After trying to run it manually from within the command line, I got the following errors.

```
WHPX: Failed to get virtual processor registers, hr=c0350005

WHPX: Failed to emulate PortIO access with EmulatorReturnStatus: 64

WHPX: Failed to exec a virtual processor
```

This used to work on previous versions of Windows Insider, now it doesn't.

Is there anything I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

It's a Windows bug that has been presented recently. There is no known solution so far.

Comment: Dude, looks like we are the only ones having this bug, I remember your name from the other forums 

Comment: they even mentioned in the previous update that ARM emulation was fixed! I still see no difference

Comment: Yeah, but that's a different kind of issue they fixed.

Comment: may I ask what computer you're using?

Comment: You are not the only ones, same problem on my AMD Ryzen 9 4900HS.

Comment: Intel i7 CPU in my case

Comment: Ok, seems it's not AMD related, but no one has acknowledged anything as of yet. has anyone a clue how to debug this further?

Comment: Run qemu manually with some debug params and/or build it from source code. I do that in WSL2 for running MacOS.

Comment: Not yet sorry. I didn't have to work on it this weekend. I'm considering installing the emulator in WSL2 and integrating it with Android Studio running on Windows itself. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I am on Ryzej 3900X - same issue here!

Comment: Ahmed - I could not manage to get simulator running inside WSL2. It was failing to start at all.

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz I'm running qemu with MacOS inside WSL2. I just had to build the latest WSL2 kernel with nested virtualization enabled. I think that the same thing applies to Android.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary fix is to turn off hypervisor until a Windows update is released. Windows 10 21296 has a known issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it an answer (cite the source) or a wish?

Comment: This is correct answer and here is Github thread regarding this bug https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6471#issuecomment-777063062

Answer (score -3):

You can go to your windows setting --> Update & Security --> Troubleshoot --> Additional troubleshooters --> Program Compatibility Troubleshooter --> choose Android Studio, now it will open and you can start your Emulator, now it come a reboot message --> reboot it and now it should works